# Optimization problem $\min_{\mathbf{p}}\ \ \log \{(2\pi e)^M\det(\mathbf{R_p})\}$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-decomposition

How to solve my optimization problem?
\begin{equation}
 \min_{\mathbf{p}}\ \ \log \{(2\pi e)^M\det(\mathbf{R_p})\}\\
 \text{s.t.} \ \ \ \ \|\mathbf{p}\| \leq s
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{p}\in \mathbb{R}^M$ is a binary vector taken from {0,1}. $\mathbf{R_p}=\Phi_{\mathbf{p}} \mathbf{R}\Phi_{\mathbf{p}}^T$ can be obtained from the covariance matrix $\mathbf{R}$ by removing the rows or columns corresponding to $p_i=0,\forall i$. And $\mathbf{R}$ is an $\mathbb{R}^{M\times M}$ matrix, $\Phi_{\mathbf{p}} \in \mathbb{R}^{\|\mathbf{p}\|_0 \times M}$ is the matrix by removing the all-zeros columns of $\text{diag}(\mathbf{p})$.

Who can tell me a trick? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there a reason that you tagged this as convex? It's definitely not.

Comment: I know my problem is non-convex,even though $\|\mathbf{p}\|_0$ is relaxed to $\|\mathbf{p}\|_1$. So the difficulty is how to reformulate $\mathbf{R_p}$ as a linear function of $\mathbf{p}$?

Comment: You don't. This is simply not a problem that can be made convex.